# symmetric product of matrices

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

**Python:** Is there any **`function F`** such that

**Input:** Two matrices A and B, two numbers

**Output:** symmetric product of the matrices.

For example:

```
F(A,B,1,1)=AB+BA
```

`F(A,B,2,1)=A^2B+ABA+BA^2`  (2 means two A matrices and 1 means one B matrix in the product) and so on.

The function is necessary for the following problem:

calculate the matrix C for various m and n (0 <=m<=L, 0<=n<=L)

```
(a*A+b*B)^{m+n}=..+a^m b^n C+..
```

A and B are rather big matrices.

Comment: You can start with matrix multiplication in numpy and build on that: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: How is the symmetric product defined? E.g. how would it behave in the case `F(A,B,3,1)`?

Comment: F(A,B,3,1)=A^3B+A^2BA+ABA^2+BA^3 
Please, see the problem above with m=3, n=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most solutions to complex problems involves splitting into smaller problems and solving them separately.

We can rewrite this problem in 2 parts:

- Generating sequences of operations.

  For example for `F(A, B, 2, 1) -> AAB+ABA+BAA` (implicit matrix multiplication)
- Computing (efficiently) those operations. We can notice that some computation will be done multiple times overall. For example when we compute `AAB+ABA+BAA` we can group all `AA` multiplication and store the result for later when needed.

To generate the sequences we can use `more_itertools` `distinct_permutations` [function](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#distinct_permutations). By encoding `A` into `0` and `B` into `1`, it generates the sequences of computation we want.

To perform the computation for one sequence, we should take advantage of previous computations. We can use memoization to memorise previous results and perform them only once.

```
# /!\ IMPORTANT: This initialization is wrong in some case, see the EDIT.
memo = {(0,): A, 
        (1,): B
       }  # should be initialized everytimes A, or B changes.

def matmul_perm(A, B, perm):
    if perm in memo:  # If previously computed, return result
        return memo[perm]

    mid = len(perm) // 2

    memo[perm] = (matmul_perm(A, B, perm[:mid]) @ 
                  matmul_perm(A, B, perm[mid:]))  # Split computation in 2 equal part and store result
    return memo[perm]
```

Now we can define our function:

```
def F(A, B, na, nb):
    s = 0
    for perm in distinct_permutations((0,)*na + (1,)*nb):
        s += matmul_perm(A, B, perm)
    return s
```

And finally test our program:

```
A = np.random.randn(50, 50)

B = np.random.randn(50, 50)

memo = {(1,): B, (0,): A}

np.max(np.abs(F(A, B, 2, 2) - (A@A@B@B + A@B@A@B + B@A@A@B + A@B@B@A + B@A@B@A + B@B@A@A)))
>>> 1.8189894035458565e-12
```

It takes about 6 sec on my computer to compute `F(A, B, 10, 10)` with `A` and `B` of size `50×50` and a fresh memo. (and less than a second to recompute it a second time)

**EDIT**

This implementation recurses forever when called with `na=nb=0`. The most simple fix is to change `memo`initialization to

```
memo = {(0,): A, 
        (1,): B,
        (): np.eye(*A.shape)  # Empty product !
       }
```

Comment: The following snippet: loops print(F(A,B,i,j)), where i and j vary in range(2) gives error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.
But if I call F many times it operates fine.
Is it possible to circumvent this?

Comment: I think the problem is when it is called with `na`or `nb` = 0. There is a fix for that, I'll edit.